# Map2stan does not work even after installing rethinking

Tags: function, package

I have successfully installed the rethinking package but its functions like quap and map2stan are still not working. "Could not find function".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have not loaded the package before using the functions:

```
library(rethinking)
```

If you don't load the function, you can still access the function using the "::" operator:

```
rethinking::quap()
rethinking::map2stan()
```